# Energy levels and degeneracy

Tags: atomic-physics

In lectures we've been told that the lowest energy level can have 2 electrons, then the next one 8 and 18 and so on. Also that the degeneracy of each level is $2n^2$. Then there's an example for Be (Z=4) in the ground state, which has two electrons in the lowest energy level and two in the next by the 'aufbau principle'. This means the degeneracy is $$\frac{8!}{2!(8-2)!} = 28$$
Is the two related to the number of electrons in the second shell or is it simply 2 because the 2nd shell is the outer shell? I don't know where each of these numbers comes from. And I can't find this equation anywhere.

I'm not finding any discussions of energy levels like those in our lectures. In particlar I'm struggling to see how this way of looking at things, with the first energy level having two electrons and $2n^2 = 2$ degenerate levels, and the second having a maximum of 8 electrons etc relates to the seemingly more common ideas of s, p, d.

Primarily, then: what do the $8$ and $2$ relate to in the degeneracy equation, and where do s, p, d come into this.

Comment: If you read through this article, especially the last part, where they list the filling out of the orbitals, you might be able to make more of your formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital  it's a long article, but there is a lot of useful information in it

Comment: The number of combinations of n objects taken r at a time is determined by the following formula: $C(n,r) = \frac  {n!}{(n -r)!r!}$